# Analog pins all reading same value

Tags: arduino-leonardo, analogread

I'm trying to read 5 analog inputs, but all the pins are reading the same as pin A0, plus or minus a couple points. I tried using pulldown resistors on all 5 pins and it made no difference. The board is a Leonardo. Thanks for any ideas/help!

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    analogReference(EXTERNAL);
}

void loop() {
    int A0, A1,A2,A3,A4;
    delay(200);
    A0= analogRead(A0);
    A1= analogRead(A1);
    A2= analogRead(A2);
    A3= analogRead(A3);
    A4= analogRead(A4);

    Serial.print(A0);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(A1);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(A2);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(A3);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(A4);
    Serial.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> int A0, A1,A2,A3,A4;
> delay(200);
> A0= analogRead(A0);
> A1= analogRead(A1);
> A2= analogRead(A2);
> A3= analogRead(A3);
> A4= analogRead(A4);
> ```

Your local variables (`A0` through `A4`) are shadowing the global variables for the pins (`A0` through `A4`). Give your local variables different names.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it must be something stupid I'd overlooked.